# Hibernate: Moving a cascaded entity from one object to another

Tags: hibernate

Consider a `Team` entity that has a collection of `Players`. The `Team` mapping allows cascaded merges and save-updates to `Players`.

I have a `Team` entity that has 4 `Players` in the database.

My service allows a user to specify a `Team`, and a `Player`, and will then do the following:

1. Creates a clone B of the existing `Team` A
2. Removes `Player` C from A and adds it to the collection in `Team` B

All of the above is done in one transaction, that only performs database queries. It does not perform updates.

A second transaction then is used to save the entities to the database. However, I'm unsure how to approach this.

My existing logic contains the following:

1. Merge `Team` B, which will effectively save Team B and then merge in `Player` C. `Player` C's version number is incremented
2. Merge `Team` A. However, this fails as the Hibernate session's `Team` A instance still has a reference to the old `Player` C's version number.

How do I go about saving these 2 entities? Do I have to save the `Player` C separately and avoid the use of cascades?

Answer (score 0):

The merge operation should not be your go-to operation when it comes to storing stuff. It is used to merge a detached entity back with the entitymanager. Very short recap of the different statuses an object can have with JPA (you might have to read up on this):

- Transient: A new object that has not yet been stored in the database (and is thus unknown to the entitymanager.) Does not have an id set.
- Managed: An object that the entitymanager keeps track of. Managed objects are what you work with within the scope of a transaction, and all changes done to a managed object will automatically be stored once the transaction is commited.
- Detached: A previously managed object that is still reachable after the transction commits. (A managed object outside a transaction.) Has an id set.

For Hibernate/JPA, the difference between a transient and a detached object is whether or not it has a value for its id field.

In order to store the object in the database, the method differs as per the status of the object.

- Transient: EntityManager.persist. This will store the object, and also make it a managed object.
- Managed: Nothing. A managed object is updated once the transaction is completed.
- Detached: EntityManager.merge. Since the entitymanager no longer recognize the object, you need to reintroduce it. Beware though, as the persist-method makes the object you pass to it managed, the merge-method does not. Instead it returns a managed copy of the object.

So, with this basis, let's look at what you are trying to do here.

First you load an object from the EntityManager. Given that you do this in the context of a transaction, this object is at the time managed. Then, you copy the object, yielding a new, transient object. Then, you make some changes to both the objects.

Next, the transaction is committed. Your managed object will then be updated, while your transient one remains transient. The managed object then survives the transaction, becoming detached. Then you store your transient object, here you should use the persist-method, not the merge method. If anything, in order to update your detached object (which should already be updated though), you will need to pass it to the merge-method.

So, in order to get proper cascade form Team to Player, you will need to add both persist and merge as cascading operations.

Also, when making the cloned object, make sure that you don't copy the id, as this would make it the same as the old one for all Hibernate can tell.

If Player C in Team A and Player C in Team B has a different version number, it can't be the same object. Perhaps something happens when you detach the objects, leading to the Player C in both teams not being the same object (but not sure about this..)